# UIDatePicker + NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

I got an UIDatePicker and want to save its state (only shows hours) after a change.
That works with:

```
myDate = [datePicker date];
NSUserDefaults *tableDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
tableDefaults setObject:myDate forKey:@"TheDate"];
```

So how can I get this back to my picker when i relaunch the app?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (myDate == nil) {
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:NO];
    } else {
        [datePicker setDate:[myDate date] animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Does not work for me, I just get the normal date / time.

Anyone who knows how to fix this? :(

Comment: Is your datePicker even initialized?  If you send a `nil` object a message it will return `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read myDate back out of NSUserDefaults, with code something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *tableDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
myDate = [tableDefaults objectForKey:@"TheDate"];
```